Menu Enter doesn't open the class
I have a menu Enter and we trying to run the follow code. However it doesn't give an error. I tried in debug mode but gives the following error Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:55697', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:55697', transport: 'socket':
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class MainActivityGame extends SurfaceView implements Runnable, SurfaceHolder.Callback   {
    private Thread gameThread = null;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private volatile boolean playing;
    private Paint paint;
    private float batWidth;
    private float batHeight;
    private float batX;
    private float batY;
    private float ballX;
    private float ballY;
    private float ballRadius;
    private float ballSpeedX;
    private float ballSpeedY;

    public MainActivityGame(Context context) {
        super(context);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Inicializa as variáveis relacionadas ao tamanho da SurfaceView
        batWidth = 200;
        batHeight = 25;
        batX = (getWidth() - batWidth) / 2;
        batY = getHeight() - 50;
        ballRadius = 25;
        ballX = getWidth() / 2;
        ballY = getHeight() / 2;
        ballSpeedX = 10;
        ballSpeedY = 15;
        // Inicia a thread do jogo
        resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        // Lógica de mudança na SurfaceView
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Lógica de destruição da SurfaceView
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (playing) {
            update();
            draw();
            control();
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        playing = false;
        try {
            gameThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void resume() {
        playing = true;
        gameThread = new Thread(this);
        gameThread.start();
    }

    private void update() {
        batX += ballSpeedX;
        if (batX <= 0 || batX + batWidth >= getWidth()) {
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        }
        batY += ballSpeedY;
        if (batY <= 0 || batY + batHeight >= getHeight()) {
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        }
        ballX += ballSpeedX;
        ballY += ballSpeedY;
        if (ballX - ballRadius <= 0 || ballX + ballRadius >= getWidth()) {
            ballSpeedX = -ballSpeedX;
        }
        if (ballY - ballRadius <= 0 || ballY + ballRadius >= getHeight()) {
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        }
        if (ballX >= batX && ballX <= batX + batWidth && ballY + ballRadius >= batY) {
            ballSpeedY = -ballSpeedY;
        }
    }

    private void draw() {
        if (surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid()) {
            Canvas canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
            paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            canvas.drawRect(batX, batY, batX + batWidth, batY + batHeight, paint);
            canvas.drawCircle(ballX, ballY, ballRadius, paint);
            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    private void control() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(30);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                batX = motionEvent.getX() - batWidth / 2;
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

